# MVC Jsp Pasar parámetros de búsqueda a edición

Tags: java, html, html5, jsp, mvc

En el momento estoy desarrollando  una aplicación que me permite buscar ciertos registros en BD  y listarlos  en una tabla  en el mismo JSP donde se genera la búsqueda.

Sin embargo la tabla la lleno en un while  con el método `.next()` de la siguiente forma:

```
<form id="form-agregar" method="post" name="form2" action="buscarModelo">                   
    <fieldset>
        <legend align="right" >Modelo a Buscar</legend>
        <label><span class="text-form2">Tipo Hardware:</span>
            <select name="txtNumId" onchange="">
            <%
                int id_hardware = 0;
             // Se instancia los recursos del modelo y se da respuesta al request 
                Servicios s = new Servicios( );
                ResultSet droplst = s.consultarHardware(id_hardware);

                if(droplst != null) {
                    while( droplst.next( ) ) { 
                        //Numero ID                //Nombre AF
                        out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getInt( 1 ) +"'>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
                    } 
                }  
            %>                                                                           
        </select></label>
        <label><span class="text-form2">Modelo del Hardware:</span><input name="txtModelo" type="text"  /></label>
    </fieldset> 
    <br/>    
    <button type="submit">BUSCAR</button>
    <button type="reset">CANCELAR</button>
</form>

<%            
   //          <!--MOSTRAR LA CONSULTA  DE  BD-->
    ResultSet lista = (ResultSet)request.getAttribute( "lista" );
    if(lista != null){
        if( lista.first()) {
            lista.beforeFirst();
                out.println("<form method='post' action=''>"
                + "<table border ='2px' align='center' name='tableedit'>"
                + "<caption align='center'> MODELOS EN BD </caption>"
                + "<tr>"
                + "<th>TIPO AF</th>"
                + "<th>MODELO</th>" 
                + "<th>EDITAR</th>"
                + "<th>ELIMINAR</th>"
                + "</tr>");

          while( lista.next( ) ){
              //Modificamos el ID hardware por el nombre para la vista
              int v = lista.getInt( 3 );
              droplst = s.consultarHardware(v);
              droplst.first();//Primera coincidencia
              String n = droplst.getString( 2 );

              out.println("<tr>"
                      + "<td >" + n + "</td>" 
                      + "<td  id='editable'>" + lista.getString( 2 ) + "</td>"
                      + "<td><a href='editarModelo.jsp?con="+ lista.getString( 1 ) +"&nomH="+ n +" &IdH="+ lista.getInt( 3 ) +"&nomM="+ lista.getString( 2 ) +"'>"
                              + "<img src='IMG/editarCampo.png' width='25' height='25'></td>"
                      + "<td><a href='eliminarModelo.jsp?con="+ lista.getString( 1 ) +"&nomH="+ n +" &IdH="+ lista.getInt( 3 ) +"&nomM="+ lista.getString( 2 ) +"'>"
                              + "<img src='IMG/eliminarCampo.png' width='25' height='25'></td>"         
                      + "</tr>");  
          } 
          out.println("</table>");                                                                            
          out.println("</form>");
        } else {
            out.println("<h2> No se encontraron Registros</h2>");
        }
    }
%>
```

Ahora mi requerimiento es pasar esa información  a otro JSP  donde se me llene el formulario  con la información  que se mostró en alguna de las filas de esa tabla.

La forma en que conseguí realizarlo fue  pasar los datos por URL con la etiqueta:

```
<a href='editarModelo.jsp?idv='prueba' &nomv='pruebanom'.......>
+ "<td><a href='editarModelo.jsp?con="+ lista.getString( 1 ) +"&nomH="+ n +" &IdH="+ lista.getInt( 3 ) +"&nomM="+ lista.getString( 2 ) +"'>"
+ "<img src='IMG/editarCampo.png' width='25' height='25'></td>"
```

Y lo  muestro en el otro JSP de la siguiente forma:

```
RECUPERAMOS LOS DATOS A MODIFICAR
-->
<%
   String con = request.getParameter( "con" );//Indice de la tabla FK
   String IdH = request.getParameter( "IdH" );
   String nomH = request.getParameter("nomH");
   String nomM = request.getParameter("nomM"); 
%>
<section id="content"><div class="ic"></div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <article class="grid_8" >
                    <div class="indent-top indent-left">
                        <br/>
                        <h3>EDITAR MODELO</h3>
                        <form id="form-agregar" method="post" name="form3" action="editarModelo">                   
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend align="right" >Datos Modelo en Edicion</legend>                                                            
                                <label><span class="text-form2">Activo Fisico:</span><input name="txtNomh" type="text"  value="<%out.println(nomH);%>" readonly="readonly"/></label>
                                <label><span class="text-form2">Modelo:</span><input name="txtNomM" type="text"  value="<%out.println(nomM);%>"></label>
                                <br/>
                            </fieldset> 
                            <label><span class="text-form2"></span><input name="txtcon" type="hidden"  value="<%out.println(con);%>"/></label>
                            <label><span class="text-form2"></span><input name="txtIdh" type="hidden"  value="<%out.println(IdH);%>"/></label>
                            <button type="submit">EDITAR</button>
                            <button type="submit"><a href="javascript:history.back(-1);" title="Página anterior">CANCELAR</a></button>
                        </form>
```

Y funciona!, Mi problema es que los  formularios estan creciendo en el desarrollo del aplicativo  y pase de 4 input a 24.

se que existen limitaciones en pasar variables por Url;  Como puedo optimizar  este proceso?  teniendo en cuenta que no es pasar información de un formulario a otro sino de una tabla obtenida por `.next()` a un formulario ?

Answer (score 1):

> se que existen limitaciones en pasar variables por Url;

1. Cantidad de 2000 caracteres en la URL, referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/3613462 Si usas Base64, te dará un error, como dirían mis hermanos de México: ya valiste x.x
2. Cuidado con pasar datos sensibles por URL, es decir, si se pueden bajar reportes por medio de un clientID, intenta cambiar por otro clientID y revisa si tu código lo permite.
3. Seguridad de XSS (inyección de código JavaScript).
4. Seguridad de SQL (inyecciones SQL).

Para este par de últimos puntos, revisa OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

> ¿Cómo puedo optimizar este proceso?

Mandar los parámetros en el body del request como POST, puedes crear hidden fields que contengan la información a enviar, te recomiendo que tengas alguna nomenclatura que te asegure que son los únicos que enviarás evitando confundir con algun otro parámetro de nombre similar.

Comment: Adicional a esta información y más propio de Java/JSP, sería recomendable dejar de usar scriptlets para procesar el request por un tema de mantenimiento a futuro de la aplicación.